# Add a JavaScript getter/setter to a native unconfigurable property

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, defineproperty

I am using special getter/setters to intercept changes made to properties of an object, and it currently works great for any normal user-defined properties. However, I would *love* if I could employ the same idea to built-in properties like `HTMLInputElement.value` or `Array.length`, but these are unfortunately defined as unconfigurable and thus I get an error when attempting to redefine them using a getter/setter.

I'm just wondering if there's any kind of (reliable) hack that I can do to force these to be redefined without breaking their internal operation.

If not, I'll probably be forced to define alternate properties for all of these that simply map to the native properties and use them instead, but that's just so not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Work with JavaScript 1.8.1 on later : [Defining getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

Answer (score -2):

that is not in any way a good practise, but if you really need to, those functions are defined on the prototype level so:

```
Array.prototype.length = (function(){})();
```

Ok, i think even this approach doesn't work with some functions, they must be protected

Comment: Yeah exactly, they're defined as unconfigurable, meaning you can't change their definition. Was just curious if there was a way around it.

Comment: [].length is *not* a function.